# How to select table DESC that contains a certain word

Tags: mysql

I have a database called mydatabase.
In mydatabase I have a few tables:

```
tablename1
tablename2
event1
event2
tablename3
event3
tablename4
```

I will have a new event table every week. How can I select the latest event table only? (in this example it's event3 but in 30 weeks it will be event30).

Or how should I create the event tables?

Comment: you should rethink your database schema again

Comment: How would it be better? Please give me an example. I'm still a beginner

Comment: I am making a registration site for our weekly soccer games. Every week the players have to register for the following event. So there will be following info: player_name, timestamp. I want to display the latest event on the site, to avoid players to register to past events. I am pretty new to mysql. Now I'm thinking about adding an "event number" column. Would that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**You should read about relational database and how MySQL works**](https://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=mysql+relational+database&gws_rd=ssl) but given the information provided, a fairly simple example would be 3 tables at best.

1. will be your registered users
2. will be your events registered
3. will be the event participants

Here is an example of what it would look like:

```
CREATE TABLE users
(
    id int auto_increment primary key, 
    name varchar(50), 
    email varchar(255)
);


CREATE TABLE events
(
    id int auto_increment primary key, 
    name varchar(50), 
    description TEXT,
    happens DATETIME
);


CREATE TABLE event_participants
(
    id int auto_increment primary key, 
    event_id int,
    user_id int
);
```

- Your users would be registered to your `users` table and every user gets an unique `ID` and as such the same user does not need to register on the website over and over to participate on an event.
- Your events are registered to your `events` table and every event gets an unique `ID`, this way you can easily search for past events, future events, and so on.
- When an user participates an event they are inserted on the `event_participants` table so you know exactly who participate on which event, you can count how many times a user participate on other events and many other things.

So here is an example:

```
INSERT INTO users (name, email)
VALUES
('John', 'john@test.com');

INSERT INTO events (name, description, happens)
VALUES
('Young Project', 'Its a soccer...', NOW());
```

As you can see above I have created an event and also have an user registered.

Now how do I put the 2 together? I reference the too on my third table like this:

```
INSERT INTO event_participants (event_id, user_id) 
VALUES
(1, 1);
```

Now how do I know a user is participating on an event? Here is a simple sample:

```
SELECT u.name AS `participantName`, e.name AS `eventName`, e.happens
  FROM event_participants ue
  JOIN users u
    ON u.id = ue.user_id
  JOIN events e
    ON e.id = ue.event_id
 WHERE e.id = 1
```

[And here is a **LIVE DEMO** of it working.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/25415/4)

You can further list all **events**:

```
SELECT * FROM events
```

Or a specific one:

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE id = 1
```

You can further list all **users**:

```
SELECT * FROM users
```

Or a specific one:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 1
```

How to select the last registered event?

```
SELECT * FROM events ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```